# How to run one off tasks in NestJS

Tags: typescript, express, nestjs, typeorm

I'm new to NestJS and i'm trying to figure out the best way to run one off initialization tasks and import tasks. In Rails you would use Rake to run the tasks, but i'm not sure what to use here. I see things like nest-commander and nestjs-cli, but those seem like you need to setup another app instance to make it work and i'm not sure if that's the proper way to handle it. I've seen other tools like Jake as well, but I would need access to my NestJS modules in the tasks. Anyone find a good way to handle this or have an example of how it's been handled well in a project?

Comment: What kind of tasks do you need to run and when do you need to run them?

Comment: @JayMcDoniel I need to run data imports/exports (to Postgres). In rails I could make rake tasks and run them from the CLI which was incredibly useful. I just don't know a great way to handle that with NestJS. I tried nest-commander and made a command.ts file, but that seemed to not work so well.

Comment: I'm the author of nest-commander, so if you're having a problem with it I'd love to help out with that. Otherwise, you would pretty much need to make JS scripts that can be ran on demand

Comment: @JayMcDoniel Are there any good docs that show how to use it in tandem with an app or example code? The docs for both NestJS and the nest-commander site itself show how to use it as a CLI app, but not in tandem.

Comment: I don't have anything immediate, but can explain the idea. You start your Nest _Server_ with `main.ts`, right? For the CLI in tandem you could make a `cli.ts` file that uses the `CommandFactory` and imports the proper root module. Then, after compiling the project instead of using `nest start` or `node dist/main` you call `node dist/cli` and run the CLI command that way. I'll see if I can find the time to write up some sort of sample

Comment: @JayMcDoniel I tried something like that (except I made a command.ts file), and it sort of worked, but A) I wasn't sure if that was the proper way to handle it and B) if you need to use TypeORM or anything that uses forRoot the command never finishes. It seems to run, but the connection never stops. Not sure if that's ok or if there is a better way to handle that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243917/discussion-between-jay-mcdoniel-and-nineblindeyes).

Answer (score 0):

In this case what I would probably do is

- create a module with a service.
- create methods that does things for you
- should have a init method that could initiate the task
- use a test to compile this module and run the test for the service method that initiates the task.

Answer (score 0):

I took took inspiration from the use of the `ConfigService` of the `@nestjs/config` package in the `main.ts` file. As described in the [documentation](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/configuration#using-in-the-maints), you can reference the service and call a method on it in the bootstrap method. Similarly, you can do it with your own service:

```
const myService = app.get(MyService);
await myService.initialiseSomething();
```